# Haskell, why do I get a prelude undefined error?

Tags: haskell

this is an exercise where I have to create my own universe of things in Haskell for a logic course. This was given to us already:

```
data Thing = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Eq,Show)

things :: [Thing]
things = [ A, B, C, D, E ]

data Colour = Amber | Blue deriving Eq

colour :: Thing -> Colour
colour A = Amber
colour B = Amber
colour C = Amber
colour D = Blue
colour E = Amber
            
data Shape = Square | Disc deriving Eq

shape :: Thing -> Shape
shape A = Square
shape B = Square
shape C = Disc
shape D = Square
shape E = Square
           
data Size = Big | Small deriving Eq

size :: Thing -> Size
size A = Big
size B = Big
size C = Big
size D = Big
size E = Small
       
data Border = Thin | Thick deriving Eq

border :: Thing -> Border
border A = Thick
border B = Thin
border C = Thick
border D = Thick
border E = Thick

type Predicate u = u -> Bool

isAmber :: Predicate Thing
isAmber x = colour x == Amber

isBlue :: Predicate Thing
isBlue x = colour x == Blue

isSquare :: Predicate Thing
isSquare x = shape x == Square

isDisc :: Predicate Thing
isDisc x = shape x == Disc

isBig :: Predicate Thing
isBig x = size x == Big

isSmall :: Predicate Thing
isSmall x = size x == Small

hasThinBorder :: Predicate Thing
hasThinBorder x = border x == Thin

hasThickBorder :: Predicate Thing
hasThickBorder x = border x == Thick
```

The following function was also given as an example of predicate negation :
neg :: Predicate u -> Predicate u
(neg a) x = not (a x)

I have to write 2 functions, one for conjunction (only true & true = true, all else is false) and disjunction (only false & false = true). I was pretty sure that this was correct, but i get the prelude undefined error when I call:

```
(|:|) :: Predicate u -> Predicate u -> Predicate u
(a |:| b) x = (a x) && (b x)

(&:&) :: Predicate u -> Predicate u -> Predicate u
(a &:& b) x = (a x) || (b x)

(|=) :: Predicate Thing -> Predicate Thing -> Bool
a |= b = [thinga | thinga <- things, a thinga] == [thingb | thingb <- things, b thingb, a thingb]

(|/=) :: Predicate Thing -> Predicate Thing -> Bool
a |/= b = not (a |= b)
```

But also, the instructions say that calling the following should work, and i do not understand how, since the x formal parameter is never used...

isBig &:& isAmber |= isDisc

That should return either true or false apparently

Example of Error

```
*Main> :reload
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> isSmall |= isDisc
False
*Main> (neg isAmber) C
False
*Main> (isBig &:& isAmber) |= isDisc
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries\base\GHC\Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at things.hs:89:15 in main:Main
```

Comment: Can you caopy&paste the actual GHCi session? Did you successfully load the file with all those definitions, so that they are brought in scope?

Comment: By the way, in a sense the formal parameter `x` _is_ used in the last line: the definition of `a |= b` calls both `a` and `b` with all the "things". Hence, the last line should indeed work. At most, it might need parentheses as in `(isBig &:& isAmber) |= isDisc`

Comment: Hi, if you could just explain how all the things are passed in by; isBig &:& isAmber |= isDisc. I might be able to figure it out! Which part of that line gets taken as the x?

Comment: Check line 89 in your file as pointed out here: `undefined, called at things.hs:89:15 in main:Main`. It looks like in your code there's an explicit use of `undefined`, unlike in the code you posted above.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything like that. https://codeshare.io/2WgkBl If you have a chance, i would appreciate it if you could look at the exact code I pasted there.

Comment: Weird indeed. I can't replicate it -- here I can run your code just fine. It looks like your GHCi is still reading the definitions with `undefined` in it. Perhaps you are loading one file, and editing another? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Thanks for doing that for me! I seem to be running the right file, but i will delete it, and make a new file :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm focusing on this part:

> and i do not understand how, since the x formal parameter is never
> used...
>
> ```
> isBig &:& isAmber |= isDisc
> ```
>
> That should return either true or false apparently

The value of `x` is chosen by `|=`, which will call both predicates `isBig &:& isAmber` and `isDisc` with all the `x` in list `things`.

Expanding the definitions:

```
isBig &:& isAmber |= isDisc
= -- according to the definition of |=
   [thinga | thinga <- things, (isBig &:& isAmber) thinga] 
   ==
   [thingb | thingb <- things, isDisc thingb, (isBig &:& isAmber) thingb]
= -- according to the definition of &:&
   [thinga | thinga <- things, isBig thinga && isAmber thinga] 
   ==
   [thingb | thingb <- things, isDisc thingb, isBig thingb && isAmber thingb]
=
   [ A, B, C ]     -- i.e., list of all things which are both big and amber
   ==
   [ C ]           -- i.e., list of all things which are discs, big, and amber
=
False         -- the two lists are not the same list
```

So, it's `thinga` and `thingb` that are passed as `x`. Those variables, in turn, assume all the values inside the list `things`, i.e. `[A,B,C,D,E]`.

Comment: Thank you! I never knew that that was possible. Really, thanks.

Comment: @RobertLutino: It may be easier to understand the definition `(a &:& b) x = (a x) && (b x)` as syntactic sugar for `(a &:& b) = \ x -> (a x) && (b x)`, that is, it defines the `&:&` operator (given two operands) as returning a lambda, which happens to be a `Predicate u`. Defining an operator this way is also sugar for a prefix definition `(&:&) a b x = …` / `(&:&) a b = \ x -> …`, which is just like a normal function definition `both a b …`. The parentheses on the right side are redundant because function application has higher precedence than operators, so you can write `a x && b x`.